# How to get a "real" production org for testing

Tags: metadata-api, sandbox, isv, production, environment-hub

*Disclaimer: I know how to create any type of orgs using the Environment Hub app.*

For our ISV app we need to test a feature that is deploying Apex classes to the user's org.

Code-Deploying on non-production orgs (Sandboxes, DE orgs) is easy but hard (and requires the use of the Metadata API) in real production orgs as they disallow the creation of classes via UI and do a full test run for each deployment from outside.

No org we can create from the Environment Hub disallows the creation of classes so we cannot test it. **Any other way to get such a "real" production org for testsing purposes?**

Is it possible for Salesforce.com to deactivate this for a given org? E.g. by "activating an org" like this error message might suggest:

> Can not create Apex Class on an active organization

Comment: How are you deploying to the target org?

Comment: Using this Apex Wrapper to the Metadata API: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/

Answer (score 1):

ISV's get a special discount on Production orgs that they can use. This is a complete list of the Partner Edition environments available and free for ISV's.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Partner_Development_%26_Test_Environments

Comment: Non of them is a "real" production org in the sense of my question.